# Co-Authors Plus Wordpress Plugin - List all the authors for same post

Tags: wordpress, author

I want to display name of multiple authors on the front end like below

By John Doe,Linn Doe and Penny

In the back end I can add many users for the same post.But In the front end only the first author on the post shows up both for the byline and the bio. I'm using Twenty Thirteen theme and how to show all the user added in the back end in the front end?

this is my single.php file

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
            <?php comments_template(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried getting help from this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-coauthors?replies=13 
.But I could not do that.

Comment: could you be more specific as to why you were not able to do that?

Comment: In single.php file there are no line like
<?php the_author(); ?> .
thats why I was unable to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Incorporate Co-Authors Plus template tags into your theme](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-coauthors?replies=13)

Other Solution:

In order to add add Co-Authors Plus support you must have access to edit the theme template. In order to display information about multiple authors on the fronted, you'll need to add the necessary Co-Authors Plus template tags to your single.php and other theme files.

Specifically for the bylines, you'll want to replace where it says something like:

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

With something like this:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?>
```

That specific snippet will allow your theme to degrade gracefully when Co-Authors Plus isn't activated.

To show the authors with their posts link, you'll want to use something like:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors_posts_links' ) ) { coauthors_posts_links(); } else { the_author_posts_link(); } ?>
```

You can use the following code for the bios

```
<?php $coauthors = get_coauthors(); ?>
<?php foreach( $coauthors as $coauthor ): ?>
<center><div class="authbio">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo $coauthor->user_firstname; ?>.jpg" alt="" class="alignleft"/>
<?php $userdata = get_userdata( $coauthor->ID ); ?>
<?php if ( $userdata->user_description ) echo $userdata->user_description; ?>
</div></center>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Reference](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-coauthors?replies=13)

Comment: I'm not good with php.theme->edit-> single.php file does not have like <?php the_author(); ?> line.can you help me please?

Comment: well in that case you simply add <?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?>

Comment: I add my single.php file to question.
I add  <?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?> line before the <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>.But is is not working.Only show first user.

Comment: Thanks @Anantha.
I was editing wrong single.php file.It's about another theme.
I use <?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?> and I can be able to show auth.or list